# Get specific data from Json File with an url with parameters

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to get a part of a jsonfile content with a specific url with parameters.
I have a results.json file contains the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have a php file where i want to get and show a part of the json output from for exmaple id = 1 with the following link

/api.php?id=1

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");

function get_feed($getid)
{

$json = file_get_contents('results3.json');
$feeds = json_decode($json);

    foreach($feeds as $feed=>$id)
    {
        if($id==$getid)
        {
            return $name;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $getid=$_GET['id'];
    $feed = get_feed($getid);
    
    if(empty($feed))
    {
        response(200,"Data Not Found",NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        response(200,"Data Found",$feed);
    }
    
}
else
{
    response(400,"Invalid Request",NULL);
}

function response($status,$status_message,$data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status);
    
    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;
    
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
```

but as result i get this when following the link /api.php?id=1

```
{"status":200,"status_message":"Data Not Found","data":null}
```

I properly don't go correctly through the array.
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have issue in how the JSON is structured and how you actually reading it:

> JSON Structure:
>
> ```
> {
>   'data' => array(
>      {},
>      {},
>   )
> }
> ```
>
> You JSON's `data` contain arrays.

You read it as:

```
foreach($feeds as $feed=>$id)
{
    if($id==$getid)
    {
        return $name;
        break;
    }
}
```

> See that you look through root JSON object, but not reading the actual arrays content of `data`

It should be like this:

```
$feeds = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($feeds['data'] as $eachData)
{
    if($eachData['id']==$getid)
    {
        return $eachData['name'];
        //no need for break, as it is not accessible because of return above.
        //break;
    }
}
```